# How many different arrangements are possible with 3 digits numbers from 1-9 if we have to arrange them in ascending order?

Tags: permutations, combinations

if there are numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 how many different three digit values we can make such that the digits are in ascending order? 
since there are numbers from 1-9, I understand that the first digit should be from 1-7 
So like that the different arrangements I found are,
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
even though I have arranged these I am confused with finding all the combinations here. they have given the answer as 84.

Comment: Yes, you answer does not include 1,2,4 and 1,2,5, etc.

Comment: yes, I just figured that out :) thank you

Comment: See this also:https://www.quora.com/How-many-3-digit-numbers-have-all-their-digits-in-an-ascending-order

Answer (score 1):

Pick any $3$ numbers out of these $9$ numbers and arrange them in ascending order. So there are $9\choose 3$ possibilities.

Comment: If we are picking any 3 numbers, we can even pick 8 or 9 as the first digit. so the second and the third digit will be lesser than the first.

Comment: I guess the OP means that each desired combination should be like 123, 456, etc. but not 132 or 546.

Comment: "Pick any 3 numbers" means that we don't count the order.  We can pick 3 numbers first, say 1, 3 and 6. If we do count the order, we have 136, 163, 316, 361, 613 and 631. But only 136 is in ascending order and the other five possibilities should be be considered. Every combination of 3 digits has 6 permutations, but exactly one of them is in ascending order. So we can first neglect the order and pick 3 digits. This gives only one combination in ascending order.

Comment: I got it now, thank youu